# Ionic loading in certan container

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `$ionicLoading` in my app controller when getting resource through api call but the default `ionicLoading` freeze the entire view, thereby preventing user to click on any other place. However , my intention is to allow user to be able to access or navigate through ionic tab while loading resource.

Is there any configuration or workaround for ionic loading to freeze only certain part of the view? E.g. inside `ion-content` or specific element id /class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a very good user experience to disallow user to access `ion-content` while accessing the tabs. Also, changing the tabs will change the `ion-content` which in turn will remove the spinner. But if you want not-obstrusive ui, you can use the `$ionicLoading.show` method with `noBackdrop` option. This is a boolean type attribute and removes the backdrop(overlay) if set to `true`, thus your view doesn't seem frozen.

```
$ionicLoading.show({
  noBackdrop: true
});
```

You can also use other options to customize your loader, as mentioned here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wr93eNLXNbFIsfGrHruT?p=preview)

Comment: It seems that i am still not able to navigate via the ion-tab after adding `noBackdrop: true`. Plunk here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/tI8lh2fvWvhTXOli94s9?p=preview)

Comment: In that case, the z-index of element with class `loading-container`, which is generated from `$ionicLoading.show`, needs to be overridden. You can use the css `.loading-container { z-index: 0 } .loading-container .loading { z-index: 13; }` . I have added link to updated plunkr in answer above. Check if it works and accept if it solves your issue